# Write a column in a Excel file from 2 different csv files having another column as a key

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 csv files of the following format-
file_name2.xlsx-

```
col1   col2 .    col3
A .    DAVID .   Music
       GILMOUR
B .    John .    Legend
       LENNON
C .    Clapton . Guitar
```

With_Comments_two.xlsx

```
Col1 .  col2 
A .     PinkFloyd
A .     Britisher
B .     Beatles
        Britisher
C .     Guitarist
        Britisher
```

I want to write col2 of second file in the first file in the below format-

```
col1   col2 .    col3 .  col4
A .    DAVID .   Music   PinkFloyd
       GILMOUR           Britisher
B .    John .    Legend .Beatles
       LENNON            Britisher
C .    Clapton . Guitar .Guitarist
                         Britisher
```

My approach-

I am reading from the 2 excel files into pandas dataframes and then trying to compare them and if common column element found then appending it to a list and then planning to write that list into first file but I don't know how to do it.
Following is my code-

```
file_name = "With_Comments_two.xlsx"
xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)
df=pd.read_excel(file_name,sheet_name="Sheet 1 - With_Comments")
file_name_two = "PythonExport.xlsx"
xl_file2 = pd.ExcelFile(file_name_two)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_name_two,sheet_name="Sheet1")
col1 = list(df.iloc[:,[0]].itertuples())
col2 = list(df2.iloc[[0]].itertuples())
col3 = df2.iloc[: ,[1]]
temp=[]
for ii in col1.itertuples():
   for jj in col2.itertuples():
      if col1[ii]==col2[jj]
        temp.append(col1[ii])
```

I don't know how to write it in file1 .Also, I don't know my procedure is correct or not. How to do it?